# No output on browser from my jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

second.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

<html>

    <body>


        <%
           try{
        String id2=(request.getParameter("ID1"));
 String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Asim Iqbal\\Documents\\IT.accdb";

 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    String sql= "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID=?";
             PreparedStatement   stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                stmt.setString(1,id2);
                ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery();
               if (rs.next())
                {
                  int i=rs.getInt("ID");
                   String nam=rs.getString("Name"); 
                   String clas=rs.getString("Class");
                   String  ph=rs.getString("Phone");
            %>
            <h1><%=i%></h1>
            <h1><%=nam%></h1>
            <h1><%=clas%></h1>
            <h1><%=ph%></h1>
            <%
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            %>

    </body>
</html>
```

No output comes from DB in the browser..
Please give me suggestion where i am getting wrong...

Comment: Did you try to view the source, to see if you get any HTML at all, like empty `<h1>` tags?

Comment: At least echo out your sql string prior to loop

Comment: I have another html page from which I am getting ID as parameter to this jsp page and try to view from this jsp page as a outuput,... RealSketptic